# How do I turn a dictionary into a table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
2021.05.03| 0.2466805
2021.05.04| 0.2602927
2021.05.05| 0.2593721
2021.05.06| 0.2605107
2021.05.07| 0.2598938
2021.05.10| 0.266119
2021.05.11| 0.2655128
2021.05.12| 0.2709233
```

I'm trying to turn it into a table, but I'm struggling.

I think it should be something like:

```
flip `date`value!myDict
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
q)([]date:key dict;val:get dict)
date       val
---------------------
2021.05.03 0.8866384
2021.05.04 0.0610109
2021.05.05 0.7806546
2021.05.06 0.501583
2021.05.07 0.04288341
2021.05.08 0.4100573
2021.05.09 0.1418907
2021.05.10 0.2533241
```

You may run into issues using `value` for a column name as it is a kdb+ key word.

```
q)([]date:key dict;value:get dict)
'assign
  [0]  ([]date:key dict;value:get dict)
                             ^
```